# Use logger in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, logging, shell

How can I use logger in a shell script?

If I run

```
ntpd -qnp pool.ntp.org 2> >(logger)
```

in console, it works as expected.

If I put it into a shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
ntpd -qnp pool.ntp.org 2> >(logger)
```

I get following error:

```
line 2: syntax error: unexpected redirection
exited with code 2
```

What is wrong in the shell script?

Comment: Can you tellwhat you are trying to achieve, and which linux distro you are using please?

Comment: I am using busybox and want to log the ntpd output, which will run as cron.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shebang is correct as both #!/bin/sh and #!/bin/bash can be used*, however, IIRC, you should use pipes not redirect for logger as it's a program not a file.

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ntpd -qnp pool.ntp.org 2>&1 |logger
```

*If you use #!/bin/sh for your scripts, they are supposed to be posix compliant, ie run well on solaris and AIX. If ever you use some bash specific features, #!/bin/bash have to be used because there's no more portability.

Comment: I tried the pipe solution, but the output is not logged in /var/log/messages but printed to the console.

Comment: Replace ntpd -qnp pool.ntp.org by echo "test" and you'll figure out if the second problem comes from logger. Be sure to check ntpd man page as setting pool.ntp.org as pidfile is not likely to work like you expect I guess.

Comment: ntpd prints to stderr, so, "ntpd -dnq -p pool.ntp.org 2>&1 |logger" does the trick :-) thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong is that you're using bash-ism's while your hash-bang is saying `/bin/sh`. Change it to `#! /bin/bash` and it will work.

Comment: That should rarely be a problem. Are there actually any systems which enforce "sh-ness" if they see "#!/bin/sh"? Note: Trying a bashism in a script flagged with "#!/bin/sh" on Linux works if you run it as "./myscript.sh" as the default shell (bash) is used but not if your run it as "sh myscript.sh" (Manual: "If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.")

Answer (score 2):

I actually had to check what the line `ntpd -qnp pool.ntp.org 2> >(logger)` does:

1. Run `ntpd -qnp pool.ntp.org`
2. Redirect its stderr using `2>` to ... where exactly? Well....
3. `>(logger)`

   1. Creates a named pipe (see [Mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution#Mechanism)), call it `/dev/fd/pipe100`
   2. Starts process `logger` reading its STDIN from that pipe
   3. Substitutes the name `/dev/fd/pipe100` into the command
4. ...thus running `ntpd -qnp pool.ntp.org 2> /dev/fd/pipe100`
5. ...while process `logger` reads from that pipe: `logger < /dev/fd/pipe100`

The above should work nicely in bash.

However, I tried to run it using "sh" explicitly, which yields:

```
script.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

So, as the other commenters noted, you are probably not using the bash here.

Indeed, Busybox uses the [Almquist Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_shell) by default.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a different shell with /bin/sh than your default shell (probably bash)

To check try to run the script with /bin/sh ./yourscript or put the same shell as $SHELL into your script

Which shell is used for /bin/sh is probably distribution dependent plus if you are on Solaris, it is something completely different.